# How to map a volume inside the ingress (nginx) pod in Minikube

Tags: lua, minikube, nginx-ingress, ingress-controller

I am using Lua code inside the Nginx ingress controller in Minikube to write some logs to a file. I would like this file to be available on the host.

Is there a way to map a volume from the ingress-controller pod to the host? I did not create the Nginx ingress controller pod using a YAML config, but merely enabled the ingress addon in Minikube, so I do not have a YAML that I can add a volume mapping to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to `kubectl get` whatever is running in your cluster and save it to a file.

```
kubectl get pod nginx -oyaml > mynginxpod.yaml
```

Then you could edit the file adding your volume and then applying with:

```
kubectl apply -f mynginxpod.yaml.
```

this is just an example.